# Codeigniter - How to validate dynamic INPUT array?

Tags: php, arrays, validation, codeigniter, input

I am not being able to run validation on an array of input fields. When I submit the form, it is submitted OK (data is saved correctly), but without validation (no errors, no messages).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

My view:

```
<?php echo form_open('save', array('id' => 'form')); ?>
    <?php foreach ($cars as $row): ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2>
                        <?php echo $row->cars_name; ?>
                    </h2>
                </td>
                <th>
                    Number
                </th>
                <td>
                    <?php echo form_input("car[$row->cars_id][cars_number]", $row->cars_number); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <th>
                    Registry
                </th>
                <td>
                    <?php echo form_input("car[$row->cars_id][cars_number_reg]", $row->cars_number_reg); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My **config/form_validation.php**:

```
'test/save' => array(
                array(
                        'field' => 'car[]', // also tried car[][], but no go
                        'label' => 'Field',
                        'rules' => 'alpha|htmlspecialchars|trim'
                     ),
                ),
```

My controller:

```
function save()
{
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $json['success'] = '0';
        $json['message'] = validation_errors();
        echo json_encode($json);

    } else {

        $car = $this->input->post('car');

        foreach ($car as $k => $v) {

            $data['cars_number']       = $v['cars_number'];
            $data['cars_number_reg']   = $v['cars_number_reg'];

            $cars_id = $k;

            $this->emergency_model->save($data, $cars_id);
        }

        $json['success'] = '1';
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a callback validation function like in this tutorial 
[in this tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the user guide [form_validation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields)

You must use the "exact" name for validation rules.
In your case validation rules should be generated in foreach, same as your view.

```
$validation_rules = array();
foreach($cars as $row){
   $validation_rules[] = array( 'field'=>'car['.$row->cars_id.'][cars_number]',
                                'Field',
                                'rules' => 'alpha|htmlspecialchars|trim'
                              );
}

$this->form_validation->set_rules($validation_rules);
```

(note:this code was not tested)

I think you have to do this in controller instead of config.